# how can i make pages ,each one contains 10 posts?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got 100 posts with Fetch API, I have all of them on the same page.
I have no idea how can i make pages where each page i can display 10 posts only .

Thats my javascript code:

```
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
       .then((res)=>res.json())
       .then((data)=>{
       let output = '<h2 class="posts"></h2>';
       let i=0;
       data.forEach(function(thePost){
        output += `
         <div style="background-color: gray;margin- 
       right:60px;width:300px;height:350px;border-radius: 30px;display: 
       inline-block;overflow: hidden;"  class="post" id=item${i}>
          <h3 style="padding:10px;color:white;">${thePost.title}</h3>
          <p style="padding:10px;color:white;">${thePost.body}</p>
        </div>
      `;
      i++;
      //if (i==3){`<br> <br>`}
    });
    document.getElementById('posts').innerHTML=output;

});
```

These are the div posts:[image: div posts]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve that.

Way 1

You can splice the array and get only the first 10 elements with `splice` method

```
data = data.splice(0, 10);
```

Full code

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
       .then((res)=>res.json())
       .then((data)=>{
       let output = '<h2 class="posts"></h2>';
       let i=0;
       data = data.splice(0, 10);
       data.forEach(function(thePost){
        output += `
         <div style="background-color: gray;margin- 
       right:60px;width:300px;height:350px;border-radius: 30px;display: 
       inline-block;overflow: hidden;"  class="post" id=item${i}>
          <h3 style="padding:10px;color:white;">${thePost.title}</h3>
          <p style="padding:10px;color:white;">${thePost.body}</p>
        </div>
      `;
      i++;
      //if (i==3){`<br> <br>`}
    });
    document.getElementById('posts').innerHTML=output;

});
```

Way 2 :

You can use pagination provided by jsonplaceholder which allows you the get only `n` posts at a given `page`.

to do that you can add some query string parameters to your request like this :

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_page=0&_limit=10
```

Full code

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_page=0&_limit=10')
       .then((res)=>res.json())
       .then((data)=>{
       let output = '<h2 class="posts"></h2>';
       let i=0;
       data.forEach(function(thePost){
        output += `
         <div style="background-color: gray;margin- 
       right:60px;width:300px;height:350px;border-radius: 30px;display: 
       inline-block;overflow: hidden;"  class="post" id=item${i}>
          <h3 style="padding:10px;color:white;">${thePost.title}</h3>
          <p style="padding:10px;color:white;">${thePost.body}</p>
        </div>
      `;
      i++;
      //if (i==3){`<br> <br>`}
    });
    document.getElementById('posts').innerHTML=output;

});
```

Comment: Thanks, for the first way , i dont wanna just get the 10 posts with Fetch , i wanna get all of them (100posts) but placing them 10 by page;

Comment: is the first approach not suitable ?

Comment: with this code, i will just get the 10 posts from the API; but i wanna get all of the posts and then place eatch 10 posts in a page . any suggestions?

Comment: you can store all the posts in an array then taking snapshots with a method and display them

Comment: how can i do that with pagination ?

Comment: Basically, you can calculate the number of pages after fetching the posts, store the result somewhere, and generate some links depending on the number of pages, on each click you run a method that slices the list and display the posts in the page, you need some DOM manipulation in order to achieve that.

Comment: its working correctly there , i copied the code and changed the app with my posts id , but nothing is  showing up !

Comment: Identifier 'allPosts' has already been declared
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: No! it's not, i changed the variable name and it says variableName has already been declared at ... ,even if its not declared anywhere

Comment: What was the issue ?

Comment: the variables you declared at the first of the code should be declared with 'var' not 'let'